# Ruby on Rails Accept post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, http-post

I need to create a Rails app that will accept a Post request from a mobile client and store the information sent with the request. I'll be using Ajax to send the request. The request is sent with the following parameters:
latitude(float)
longitude(float)
timestamp(Javascript Date object)

I've already created a data model with the appropriate fields using rails generate resource,
but I'm not sure how to get Rails to accept the Post request and create an object with the necessary information. How should I edit the code Rails generated to make this happen?

Thanks, and I apologize for asking such an elementary question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell how much you know about Rails from this question, but this is all really basic Rails functionality, so you kindof need to start from the beginning... if you do these two tutorials, you'll be able to get started:

1. Learn [Rails Controllers](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)
2. Learn [Rails Routing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Then give it a shot creating a new controller and some routes that match what you're looking for, then you can use a mozilla plugin like RESTClient to test your routes with some dummy data.

But seriously, first step here is "Learn Rails".  :)

Comment: My problem is with the controller. I've been trying to pass parameters to Report controller's create method. As I understand it, entering "http://localhost:3000/reports/create/1?latitude=4" into the address bar should create a new report whose latitude field = 4. Yet the report object that is saved to the database has only empty fields.

Comment: Then I have another tutorial for you:  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html  you should be running your server in debug mode and paying attention to the output, you can then dump your params to the console and start debugging - start by testing whether your latitude param is getting into the controller at all.

Comment: Ok, so I finally got Report#create to accept the parameters specified in the URL. Previously the code was @report=Report.new(params[:report]). I had to explicitly list the parameters for it to accept them @report=Report.new({latitude:params[:latitude]}). Is there any reason why I had to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, well, @report=Report.new(params[:report]) is wrong, it would be @report=Report.new(params[:latitude]), did that not work?  And why does your route have a 1? that's not generally a create route, but a member route where you're editing an existing object (with and Id of 1)